# Replacing a special set of html tags (combination of tags) with null

Tags: javascript

I am using an editor for entering text data, each `Enter` key (keyboard `Enter` key) treated as `"<div><br></div>"`. I am used 2 enter key inside textarea the output becomes:

```
"<div><br></div><div><br></div>"
```

I can easily remove this combination of tags (`<div><br></div>`) using string replace method:

```
var myText = myText.replace(/<div><br><\/div>/g,'');
```

but my problem is

Entered a string and follows 2 `Enter` key and again typed a string, in this case i want the result looks like

```
hi<div><br></div><div><br></div>hi
```

but i applied above "string replace" method  and the output becomes `"hi<div>hi</div>"`, all the `Enter` key values are gone.

But I want to keep that enter key values(`<div><br></div>`) inside the string. Output looks like

```
"hi<div><br></div><div>hi</div>"
```

So I want to replace the tags before or after a string, not inside any string.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a different approach where you don't have to manipulate data with the replace method or regex. It works while the user types and is computed by the keyCode the user types in.

A different approach to your problem, but works in a nice way without much hassle and very easy to read...

Please have in mind that I code this quickly and you need to refactor or tidy up properly:

```js
var myText = ''

window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, false)

function handleKeydown (e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 13) {
   handleEnterKey(e)
 } else {
   concat(e)
 }
 console.log(myText)
}

function concat (e) {
  return myText += String.fromCharCode(e.which)  
}

function handleEnterKey (e) {
  return myText += '<div><br></div>'
}
```